# Java process getting crashed

Tags: java

java process is getting crashed , i checked into log it says 99% of perm gen memory reached , but i have set the max perm gen memory to 128MB . seems like max perm gen memory is not going beyond 98 MB

jre version - 1.6.

any suggestions what may be the issue

Comment: Can you say why you believe the max perm gen size is 98 MB if its 99% full of 128 MB?  What happens if you increase the maximum to 256 MB?

Answer (score 2):

Use jvisualvm (it's in your Java instalation folder) to watch perm gen space. Maybe you have some kind of memory leak in that space. Watch number of classess loaded. Is it desktop application or web? Are you redeploying on Tomcat (it has perm gen space issues)?

Comment: i checked thru visual vm ... memory is not increasing beyong 98 and it crashes after that..... in th ecrash report perm gen has reached 99% ...less that wht is allocated ...this happening only in windows on lunux its working f9

Comment: Afer application init perm gen in jvisualvm reaches stable level and don't increase anymore, true? If so try to increase max perm size - make it 30% larger than you expect.  How does the crash look like? Some kind of exception? Windows process crash? Does it crash right after start or does it work some time?

Answer (score 0):

Perm size is controlled by  -XX:MaxPermSize option.
Usually, default value is -XX:MaxPermSize=64m and you could try to increase it.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html for details.

Comment: -XX:MaxPermSize option. i have set to 196mb , still ... it not going beyond 98 mb... is it some issue specific to 64bit java 6.0

Comment: It probably means that you;re trying to load too many clases.
Try using the JVM options -XX:+TraceClassLoading and -XX:+TraceClassUnloading to see what classes are loaded/un-loaded in real-time.  If you have doubts about excessive class loading in your app; this might help you find out exactly what classes are loaded and where.